# choppy graphics when playing .mkv vidoe with VLC on ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia gpu

Tags: screen, tearing

just started using ubuntu. I'm a total noob so if you need more info please let me know what it is and how to do it. I'm trying to play .mkv files using VLC on my laptop. I have a gtx 1070 installed, and I'm using whatever the default driver is from ubuntu install. Basically I'm seeing screen tearing/choppy graphics. I haven't tired playing any games yet, but I'm assuming if I have problems with just videos the games will probably be just as bad. Before I get off topic, I want to know if anyone has some information about improving the quality of videos or updating drivers for best performance. Please let me know what I can do to fix the screen tear/choppy video, thank you.

this is the laptop: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834234297R

Comment: try installing the latest drivers, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) might help you.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I gave you the step by step guide, press on the 'this' word in my 1st comment.

Comment: thanks, that worked, but I was getting stuck in a login loop. I figured out what the problem was. At the end of installation I was prompted if I wanted to disable secure boot on my device because 3rd party drivers won't work with it enabled. I clicked yes to disable, but apparently the changes didn't take place. I had to go into bios and do it myself, after that the login loop stopped and the drivers are working great.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you solved it. Please post your solution in the answer below, and mark this post as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed latest nvidia drivers and after reboot I would get stuck in a log in loop. Would have to purge nvidia in order to stop the loop from happening. The problem is that at the end of the installation there's a prompt that says the driver won't work if secure boot is enabled would you like to disable it y/n? I would click yes to disable it and assumed that it would change it for me. It did not. I had to disable secure boot in bios than I was able to boot + log in without any issues and the drivers are working great, I can even play some steam games.